# Loop to create files by iterating over array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I've encountered a bug with the logic of my Bash script. I have an array, containing number, uppercase, and lowercase values that I'm attempting to loop over and create files based off the array value. All the number files get created, as do the lowercase files, but the uppercase files do not get created.

I've attempted to debug the script using `bash +x scriptname.sh`, and that shows that the files are created, but they don't appear in the directory. I've also done an `echo "${LETTERNUM[k]}"` which shows that the loop is iterating the correct amount of times.

Side question, is there a cleaner way to do this? I feel like the repeated call of `${LETTERNUM[k]}` might not be the best -- is there a different/better way to print that out 8 times? And I'm sure there are other ways such as `touch{a..z}` to generate the files, but I need the array for another part of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a LETTERNUM=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0");

for (( k=0; k<=61; k++ ))
do

     > "${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}${LETTERNUM[k]}".txt
done
```

Comment: "the files are created, but they don't appear in the directory" What does that mean?

Comment: When I run the bash +x command on the script -- whether it's using touch or > -- it shows the output, such as 'touch MMMMMMMM.txt'. The uppercase files are not present in that directory, despite the lowercase files and number files being there.

Comment: Maybe you are on a Mac with a case-insensitve filesystem?

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu image via Vagrant, but my host is MacOS. Perhaps because it's a shared directory?

Comment: It's because of the shared directory! I moved it out of there and reran it, so it was fully on the Ubuntu image, and it worked. Thanks @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, iterating through the array directly and using touch command to create the files :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a LETTERNUM=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0");

for i in "${LETTERNUM[@]}"
do
    touch $i.txt
done
```

Comment: This is definitely cleaner (so thanks!) but I'm still not getting the capital letters, such as AAAAAAAA.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed it to make the generation of the filename a bit cleaner. About the capital letters, I haven't been able to replicate the error since all the files are being generated correctly on my system, including the capitals.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a LETTERNUM=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0");

for i in "${LETTERNUM[@]}"; do
    touch $(printf "${i}%.0s" {1..8})".txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were trying to get all upper and lower characters and digits `[0-9]` as elements of an indexed array, I'd just use a character string containing the wanted characters, loop over the length and use *string index* to add each character to the array. There are some utilities that will create character sequences, but none are guaranteed to be installed.

A quick approach using a C-style `for` loop would be:

```
## string containing all characters
c=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHINJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

## loop over each char
for ((i = 0; i < ${#c}; i++)); do
    a+=( ${c:i:1} )     ## add each char as array element
done
declare -p a   ## output filled array to confirm
```

You can copy/middle-mouse paste into your terminal to see the array formed:

```
$ c=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHINJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
> for ((i = 0; i < ${#c}; i++)); do
>     a+=( ${c:i:1} )
> done
> declare -p a
declare -a a='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d" [4]="e" [5]="f" [6]="g" [7]="h" 
[8]="i" [9]="j" [10]="k" [11]="l" [12]="m" [13]="n" [14]="o" [15]="p" 
[16]="q" [17]="r" [18]="s" [19]="t" [20]="u" [21]="v" [22]="w" [23]="x" 
[24]="y" [25]="z" [26]="A" [27]="B" [28]="C" [29]="D" [30]="E" [31]="F" 
[32]="G" [33]="H" [34]="I" [35]="N" [36]="J" [37]="L" [38]="M" [39]="N" 
[40]="O" [41]="P" [42]="Q" [43]="R" [44]="S" [45]="T" [46]="U" [47]="V" 
[48]="W" [49]="X" [50]="Y" [51]="Z" [52]="0" [53]="1" [54]="2" [55]="3" 
[56]="4" [57]="5" [58]="6" [59]="7" [60]="8" [61]="9")'
```

There are probably a number of different ways, but efficiency-wise the built-in string-index parameter expansion is probably about a fast as any for 61 characters.